# How can i validate mutliple forms in a single html page with jquery?

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src={{ url_for('get_file', filename='jq') }}></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var x = "{{msg}}"
            var name= {{ name | safe}}
            console.log(name[0])
            console.log(x=='', name)
            // $('.alert').hide()
            // if (x!=''){
            //     $('.alert').show()
            // }
            $( "#locations" )[0].scrollIntoView();
            
            $('#lname').on("change", function(){
                var txt = $(this).val().toLowerCase()
                console.log(txt)
                for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                    if (name[i]==txt){
                        console.log('x')
                        $(this).addClass("error")
                        break
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).removeClass("error")
                        $(this).addClass("okay")
                    }
                }
              });

          });
    // validator
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.container').submit(function(e) {
            var empty = $(this).find("input").filter(function() {
                return this.value === "";
            });
            if (empty.length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Cannot submit empty field");
            }
        });
    });


    
     
      

    </script>
    <style>
        .okay{
            border-color:#0F0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border-width: 4px;
        }
        .error{
            border-color:#F00;
        }
        .weekDays-selector input {
          display: none!important;
        }

        .weekDays-selector input[type=checkbox] + label {
          display: inline-block;
          border-radius: 6px;
          background: #dddddd;
          height: 40px;
          width: 30px;
          margin-right: 3px;
          line-height: 40px;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .weekDays-selector input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
          background: #2AD705;
          color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style> 
</head>
{% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <form action={{ url_for('add_category_details') }}  method="post" name="loginform">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <th colspan="2"> Add Persons Category </th>
                        <tr class="table-info"> 
                        <tr id='new_cat' class="table-info">
                          <td> Enter New Category Name: </td>
                          <td><input type='text' name='lname' style="width:200px;" value=""></td>
                        </tr>                       
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2">
                            <button id='confirm' name='confirm' type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block active">Confirm</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>        
                    </tr>
                </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        
        </form>
<!-- add forms in seperate divs -->
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form action={{ url_for('delete_category_details') }} method="post" name="loginform" >
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                      <th colspan="2"> Delete Persons Category </th>
                      <tr class="table-info"> 
                      <tr id='new_cat' class="table-info">
                        <td> Select Category Name: </td>
                        <td>
                          <select name="lname" id="lname" style="width:200px;">
                            {% for row in lname %}
                              <option selected disabled hidden>Select a category</option>
                              <option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                        </td>
                      </tr>                       
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <button id='confirm' name='confirm' type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block active">Confirm</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>        
                  </tr>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
        <!-- form with two input dropdowns one as old category and other as new category displaying the existing categpry name -->
        <!-- todo -->
        <!-- form to accept color name choiced from color table in person db and category name calls update_color route -->  
    <div class="container">
        <form action={{ url_for('update_color_category') }} method="post" name="loginform">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                      <th colspan="2"> Update Persons Category Color </th>
                      <tr class="table-info"> 
                      <tr id='new_cat' class="table-info">
                        <td> Select Category Name: </td>
                        <td>
                          <select name="category" id="category" style="width:200px;">
                            {% for row in lname %}
                              <option selected disabled hidden>Select a category</option>
                              <option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                        </td>
                      </tr> 
                      <tr id='new_cat' class="table-info">
                        <td> Select Category Color: </td>
                        <td>
                          <select name="color" id="color" style="width:200px;">
                            {% for row in color %}
                              <option selected disabled hidden>Choose a color</option>
                              <option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                        </td>
                      </tr>                      
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <button id='confirm' name='confirm' type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block active">Confirm</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>        
                  </tr>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<!-- display in a table categpry name and their respective color with the use of dictionary category_color -->
    <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                      <th colspan="2"> Category Name and Color </th>
                      <tr class="table-info"> 
                      <tr id='new_cat' class="table-info">
                        <td> Category Name: </td>
                        <td> Category Color: </td>
                      </tr> 
                      {% for key, value in category_color.items() %}
                      <tr id='new_cat' class="table-info">
                        <td> {{key}} </td>
                        <td> {{value}} </td>
                      </tr> 
                      {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
        <!-- <table class="table table-hover" id='locations'>
          <thead>
            <th> List of Added Categories</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for row in lname %}
                <tr class="table-info">
                  <td width="10px">{{row}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>  
          
        </table>   -->
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

so I added a jquery function to validate the multiple forms in a single html page but it is only able to validate the first form and not the forms after that, whenever I submit the other two forms it triggers api call and displays bad request, when I checked the console logs it displays error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollIntoView')` is it due to the fact that they are seperate divs or is something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollIntoView')

This is likely because your `table` with `id='locations'` is commented out, and therefore `$( "#locations" )[0]` is undefined.

> it is only able to validate the first form and not the forms after that

Your validation script appears to be looking for `$(this).find("input")` - but only your first form has any `<input>` tags! You might be able to fix this by also looking for `<select>` tags: `$(this).find("input,select")`.

Comment: so uncommented the  ```$( "#locations" )[0].scrollIntoView();``` that solved the first error but i added the second solution ```$(this).find("input,select")``` it still not displaying alert rather submit the form and giving me error bad request. I tried adding onsubmit but that also worked for only one form.